# $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p-1}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p}$ and

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to proof that when dividing the first series with $p$, the remainder is $p-1$ and when dividing the second series with $p$ ($p>2$) the remainder is $0$. I understand that I need to use Fermat's little theorem, and maybe the special case of it, but have problems applying it. And help of hints would be superb as I seem to be stuck...

David

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752413/problem-modulo-p) duplicate for the second question.

Comment: Is $p$, as is usual with that letter, a prime?

Comment: Yes sorry, should have stated that. In the case of the second series, the prime is larger than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod{p},\, \forall p\nmid k$$
$$k^{p}\equiv k \mod{p},\, \forall p$$
So the summations can be simplified to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p-1}\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}1\equiv p-1\mod{p}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p}\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k\equiv \frac12p(p-1)\equiv0\mod{p}$$

Comment: Hi Peter,

Many thanks for this. Both of the first statements follow from Fermat's Little Theorem, correct?

David

Comment: The only thing beyond my understanding is how it's possible to simplify the first series when the first statement in your comment only is applicable for ∀∤. Doesn't that mean that all terms -terms in the series have to be non-divisible by ? Sorry for the questions, first time trying to wrap my head around congruency etc.

Comment: Yes, but this is trivially true as $p\gt k$ for all $1\le k \le p-1$ so it's impossible for $p$ to divide $k$. This is because $p|k\implies p\le k$.

Comment: Of course, many thanks for this again!

Comment: Is the reason that the  has to be larger than 2 in the second series that the arithmetic sum simplification does not work if the sum only contains one term (which is the case if  = 2)?

Comment: $p$ has to be larger than $2$ because we need $\frac12(p-1)$ to be an integer such that when multiplied by $p$ we get a number divisible by $p$. If we have $p=2$ then $\frac12(p-1)=\frac12$ so we cannot conclude that $\frac12p(p-1)\equiv0\mod{p}$.